# How to use dialyxir on local?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have `dialyxir` in mix.exs file under phoenix project:

```
{:dialyxir, "~> 0.5", only: [:dev, :test], runtime: false}
```

But when run `mix dialyzer` under project path, got this error:

```
$ mix dialyzer
Checking PLT...
[:asn1, :certifi, :compiler, :connection, :cowboy, :cowlib, :crypto,
 :db_connection, :decimal, :eex, :elixir, :ex_json_schema, :eye_drops,
 :fastglobal, :forge, :fs, :gettext, :hackney, :httpoison, :idna, :kernel,
 :logger, :logger_file_backend, :mariaex, :metrics, :mime, :mimerl, :mnemonics,
 :parse_trans, :phoenix, :phoenix_html, :phoenix_pubsub, :plug, :poison,
 :pqueue, :pqueue2, :public_key, :ranch, :relax_yaml, :runtime_tools, :sentry,
 :ssl, :ssl_verify_fun, :stdlib, :stream_gzip, :syntax_tools,
 :unicode_util_compat, :uuid, :yamerl]
Finding suitable PLTs
Looking up modules in dialyxir_erlang-19.3_elixir-1.5.1_deps-dev.plt
Looking up modules in dialyxir_erlang-19.3_elixir-1.5.1.plt
Looking up modules in dialyxir_erlang-19.3.plt
Finding applications for dialyxir_erlang-19.3.plt
Finding modules for dialyxir_erlang-19.3.plt
Creating dialyxir_erlang-19.3.plt
:dialyzer.run error:     The PLT file _build/.mix/dialyxir_erlang-19.3.plt is not writable
Looking up modules in dialyxir_erlang-19.3.plt
** (Mix) Could not open _build/.mix/dialyxir_erlang-19.3.plt: no such file or directory
```

I also tried to install it again following the official site:

```
mix do deps.get, deps.compile
```

But, I got the same result. What's the problem?

> https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir

Comment: seems you have some file probs: ```_build/.mix/dialyxir_erlang-19.3.plt is not writable``` the file is not writeable.Can you test manually to touch a file in this dir and to modify it?

Comment: @Pfitz Yes, you are right. After I created a path `_build/.mix`, it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems you have some file probs: _build/.mix/dialyxir_erlang-19.3.plt is not writable the file is not writeable.Can you test manually to touch a file in this dir and to modify it?

Comment: Yes. I had made a new path `_build/.mix`. Then it works.